# Make Y axis total in stacked ggplot2 bar chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is like

```
samples <- c(rep("M-NF" , 3) , rep("M-Q" , 3) , rep("NF" , 3) , rep("Q-RN" , 3) )
variablex <- rep(c("miRNA" , "lncRNA" , "sRNA") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(samples,variablex,value)
```

But there are 576 rows ( each of 48 samples has 12 variablex values)

I want a stacked bar plot with the total values on the y axis, I don't need the individual values (all the totals for each sample are between 100 and 200).

Here is the code I'm using to generate the plot

```
ggplot(df3, aes(fill=variablex, y=value, x=samples)) + geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "stack") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0))
```

Here is an image of my plot with axis

[image: barplot]

How can I make this an ordinary axis with normal intervals going up to 200?

Comment: The image didn't load https://imgur.com/a/RvXM3EA

Comment: Please check whether your `value` column is actually numeric. Seems to be a factor.

Comment: It wasn't! I changed is with as.numeric() and the plot looks perfect. Thankyou.